# How can I get the required column from this table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm putting together a simple report card system in Laravel just as a learning tool. At present I have a `Pupil` table, a `Subject` table, and a `Pupil_Subject` pivot table consisting of `id, pupil_id, subject_id,` and `grade` columns.

I have the Pupil and Subject model relationships both set to `belongsToMany`. However, if I run, for example, `$pupil = App\Pupil::find(1)->subjects` in Tinker, I get the following output:

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#729
     all: [
       App\Subject {#726
         id: 1,
         subjectname: "English",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#731
           pupil_id: 1,
           subject_id: 1,
         },
       },
       App\Subject {#728
         id: 2,
         subjectname: "Maths",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#730
           pupil_id: 1,
           subject_id: 2,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

With no pupil information for pupil(1), and no sign of the grade column in `subjects`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get both `Pupil` and `Subject` objects, use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$pupil = App\Pupil::with('subjects')->find(1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how can I access the `grade` property of each entry in the pivot table?

Comment: @user4676723 you should use `withPivot()` method in your relationship and then iterate over `subjects` and get the property with `->pivot->grade`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many